# How to disable auto inclusion of field annotations in generated constructor in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a trouble finding right setting in IntelliJ IDEA after one of the latest update. 
I often use code generation, and now it always includes field's annotations in generated constructors. For instance, I have a simple model for which I want to generate constructor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QbY8.png

The output of above is that my constructor parameters contain all field's annotations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9I0H.png

Sample code before generating constructor:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class TestModel {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Email
    private String login;
}
```

My question is, how can I disable auto-inclusion of annotations in constructor parameters?

Comment: Try this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205418670-How-to-disable-parameter-hints-for-constructors-only-
if it doesnt help, pls. provide your code or a working minimal version on GitHub.
Also provide IntelliJ/JDK Versions.

Comment: @hce it doesn't solve my issue. I don't want to disable parameters hints, but instead I want to disable auto generated annotations around constructor parameters. I am using IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2018.2.7 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: @hce I have updated my original post with sample code.

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid, there is no option in the settings for the constructor generator. request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Although not what you wanted: You could generate a parameterless constructor, when you click on 'select none' in the constructor generator.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Unfortunaly, it is not my case with parameterless constructor. I usually use 'generate constructor' function with many parameters and since last update I always have to remove unnecessary annotations what is annoying. In previous versions it didn't work like this, and therefore I thought there is an option to disable this behavior.

Comment: If anyone is interested in tracking status of the issue, there is a Jira ticket for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206570